# The blur filter doesn't work on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js, blur

I recently had a problem with the blur filter in the "Canva" node.js module.

It just doesn't work and there is no error or anything else

```js
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(560, 315);

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
    ctx.filter = "blur(500)"
```

**The problem has been patch**

Comment: Looks like [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) doesn't support the filter API yet. See [this](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1063) issue for more information.

Comment: I suggest using an API for image manipulation, if your interested I have actually coded one myself, for image manipulation, it makes memes and blurs images etc.....